# pandas build on Cygwin

Tags: python, pandas, cygwin

I tried building pandas on Cygwin and run into an error building pandas.msgpack._packer:

```
building 'pandas.msgpack._packer' extension
```

The error is:

```
gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory
```

And here's the build command:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.3-1.x86_64/build=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.3-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python3/python3-3.4.3-1.x86_64/src/Python-3.4.3=/usr/src/debug/python3-3.4.3-1 -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN__=1 -Ipandas/src/msgpack -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/tmp/pip-build-mdmyz2dz/pandas/.eggs/numpy-1.10.2-py3.4-cygwin-2.3.1-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c pandas/msgpack/_packer.cpp -o build/temp.cygwin-2.3.1-x86_64-3.4/pandas/msgpack/_packer.o
```

I'm guessing that gcc isn't finding `pandas/src/msgpack` and its subdirectories because the prior builds use all the other links except for these.

I guess, my question is, has anyone tried to install pandas on Cygwin's python? If not, any clues on what's going on here?

Comment: I've got no answer for you, but I've got the same problem. If you sorted this out, please do share the answer for the betterment of all the teeming masses whose employers insist on Windows. ;-)

Comment: unfortunately, I have not figured this out. I can install numpy but am stuck at pandas. I'll keep you updated in this ever continuing saga.

Comment: Also trying to do this at the moment. Please update if you ever figured this out.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry no, I haven't figured it out and haven't been working on it for a while...

Answer (score 6):

Install the following packages in cygwin :

```
python2-numpy
python2-six
python2-wheel
python2-setuptools
python2-pip
python2-cython
gcc-core
gcc-fortran
gcc-g++
make
wget
```

And then in Cygwin Terminal, build and install

```
pip2 install pytz python-dateutil
pip2 install pandas
```

Comment: I also had to install `python2-devel`.

Comment: for python3.9 I also needed `cmake`

Answer (score 2):

I successfully built pandas 0.18.1, I had to install `gcc-g++`.

If you're using baboon: `pact install gcc-g++`

Answer (score 2):

this below is taken from another website, https://wiki.usask.ca/display/MESH/Running+Python+from+the+Cygwin+Terminal.

I report the steps below but all credit goes to the original writer.

**Configuring Cygwin**

Download and run the Cygwin installer: setup-x86.exe for 32-bit or setup-x86_64.exe for 64-bit (source: http://cygwin.com/install.html).

Search for and mark the following packages for installation:

- \All\Devel\make
- \All\Devel\gcc-core
- \All\Devel\gcc-fortran
- \All\Devel\gcc-g++
- \All\Python\python
- \All\Web\wget

**Installing Python**

Run "Cygwin Terminal" (mintty.exe) as an Administrator. Install Python using the following command:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

Install additional packages, as required:

```
easy_install --upgrade numpy
easy_install "python-dateutil==1.5"
easy_install --upgrade pytz
easy_install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: Feeling proud -- I went to U of Sask. Just a shout out!

Comment: This one worked for me, even on Python 3.8. I am not an expert, so far `import pandas` works, I don't know if something else will go wrong when using it. 

I got a couple of issues. (i) I had to run `2to3` on files in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_dateutil-1.5-py3.8.egg" (ii) But `easy_install --upgrade pandas` gave `error: The 'python-dateutil>=2.7.3' distribution was not found and is required by pandas` at the end, which I resolved by `easy_install "python-dateutil==2.7.3" ` and then rerunning `easy_install --upgrade pandas`

Answer (score 2):

For Python3.7 + on *Cygwin* do the following.

These instructions assume that `python3` *Cygwin* package is not installed.

Install latest versions of following Packages using the *Cygwin* installer:

```
python37
python37-pip
python37-setuptools
python37-devel
```

Open the Cygwin terminal and run the following steps there.

Create symlink for `/usr/bin/python3`:

```
% ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3
```

Upgrade pip:

```
% python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Upgrade other packages:

```
% python3 -m pip list --outdated
```

... for each package that is outdated run:

```
% python3 -m pip install --upgrade <package>
```

Install pandas and dependencies (note: this takes quite a while):

```
% python3 -m pip install cython wheel pandas
```

Comment: I did several iterations of this with Python 3.8 but got some error or other, e.g. 

 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6016_sg2/numpy_9094584bd76f4a528bba080671dbec8f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='
"'"'/tmp/pip-install-6016_sg2/numpy_9094584bd76f4a528bba080671dbec8f/setup.py'"'"'[...] --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-gmderm5i/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-gmderm5i/overlay/include/python3.8/numpy Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Be wary of building complex packages using Python 3.8+ on Cygwin at this time. I have found that Python 3.7.x is very well supported and tested but last time I checked, around mid 2020, but 3.8.x was still pretty sketchy. That should change eventually once the maintainers put more focus on 3.8.x. For this reason, my waterline for Python development is 3.7.x as I depend on Cygwin from time to time for my python tools.

Comment: I was able to get it work with easy_install as I wrote in another comment above. I am quite new to python and I did see it said easy_install is deprecated. Would you suggest I get rid of 3.8 and try your method with 3.7?

Comment: For Cygwin, I would definitely recommend v3.7 at this time.